# Target database is not up to date

Tags: alembic

I'd like to make a migration for a Flask app. I am using Alembic.

However, I receive the following error.

```
Target database is not up to date.
```

Online, I read that it has something to do with this.
http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html#building-an-up-to-date-database-from-scratch

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand how to get the database up to date and where/how I should write the code given in the link.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

After creating a migration, either manually or as `--autogenerate`, you must apply it with `alembic upgrade head`.  If you used `db.create_all()` from a shell, you can use `alembic stamp head` to indicate that the current state of the database represents the application of all migrations.

Answer (score 167):

This Worked For me

```
$ flask db stamp head
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db upgrade
```

Comment: Commands for flask only! It's not alembic

Incompaitable with other web frameworks

Comment: i know it has been nearly 4 years .. but i found this very helpful..!! it worked for me.. 
my error was
[SQL: ALTER TABLE song ADD COLUMN filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
now the best part was even after delleting the column or removing the database table and or downgrading the migrate this error was not going... and even in the age of generative AI which was making me go round in circles for 4 hours.. this solution was not provided..thank you verymuch

Answer (score 45):

My stuation is like this question, When I execute "./manage.py db migrate -m 'Add relationship'", the error occused like this "
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Target database is not up to date."

So I checked the status of my migrate:

```
(venv) ]#./manage.py db heads
d996b44eca57 (head)
(venv) ]#./manage.py db current
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
715f79abbd75
```

and found that the heads and the current are different!

I fixed it by doing this steps:

```
(venv)]#./manage.py db stamp heads
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running stamp_revision 715f79abbd75 -> d996b44eca57
```

And now the current is same to the head

```
(venv) ]#./manage.py db current
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
d996b44eca57 (head)
```

And now I can do the migrate again.

Comment: Works like a charm ! I feel this is the best way to manage this issue !

Comment: Same here! Worked smooth. I knew it had do with db heads and current, but didn't know there is "stamp" command. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

This can be solved bby many ways :

1 To fix this error, delete the latest migration file ( a python file) then try to perform a migration afresh.

If issue still persists try these commands :

```
$ flask db stamp head  # To set the revision in the database to the head, without performing any migrations. You can change head to the required change you want.
$ flask db migrate     # To detect automatically all the changes.
$ flask db upgrade     # To apply all the changes.
```

Comment: I deleted the latest migration file. Its works! thx

Comment: 3 years later and still a gem :)

Answer (score 14):

```
$ flask db stamp head  # To set the revision in the database to the head, without performing any migrations. You can change head to the required change you want.
$ flask db migrate  # To detect automatically all the changes.
$ flask db upgrade  # To apply all the changes.
```

You can find more info at the documentation https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 11):

I had to delete some of my migration files for some reason. Not sure why. But that fixed the problem, kind of.

One issue is that the database ends up getting updated properly, with all the new tables, etc, but the migration files themselves don't show any changes when I use automigrate.

If someone has a better solution, please let me know, as right now my solution is kind of hacky.

Comment: I know it is a bit old now, but do your tables inherit from Base? I had the same issue and automigrate wasn't picking up changes due to the fact that my new tables weren't inheriting from Base where base is `Base = declarative_base()
` and also remember `from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
`

Answer (score 5):

To fix this error, delete the latest migration file ( a python file) then try to perform a migration afresh.

Comment: This worked for me when I wanted to regenerate a migration file because the first was incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

I did too run into different heads and I wanted to change one of the fields from string to integer, so first run:

```
$ flask db stamp head # to make the current the same
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db upgrade
```

It's solved now!

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you, like myself, have just started a new project and you are using in-memory SQLite database (`sqlite:///:memory:`). If you apply a migration on such a database, obviously the next time you want to say auto-generate a revision, the database will still be in its original state (empty), so alembic will be complaining that the target database is not up to date. The solution is to switch to a persisted database.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem input with `flask db migrate`
I used
`flask db stamp head`
and then
`flask db migrate`

Answer (score 1):

To solve this manually, you could **delete the '.py' files inside alembic\versions** which means deleting the previous versions of the database.

**Then run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Your message"` 
Followed by `alembic upgrade head` .**

This worked for me.

Answer (score -7):

To solve this, I drop(delete) the tables in migration and run these commands

```
flask db migrate
```

and

```
flask db upgrade
```