# Alembic Second Database First Revision

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, alembic

My goal is to add a second database to my current project, using alembic. I have the default alembic folder, and using 'alembic init alembic_second' I created a second folder structure. I modified the env.py in the second folder and the root alembic.ini. When I run

```
alembic -n 'alembic_second' revision -m "create second"  --head=base  --version-path=alembic_second/versions --autogenerate
```

the output is:

```
postgresql:// (all the correct second database connection stuff)
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
ERROR [alembic.util] Target database is not up to date.
  FAILED: Target database is not up to date.
```

postgresql://(all the correct second database info)

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768940/target-database-is-not-up-to-date) doesn't work for me because my new versions folder is empty, my problem is I can't run my FIRST migration on this new database. As you can see in my terminal input, I am specifying the new versions folder.

Also, I put a print statement in my second env.py, and I am successfully seeing that, so it is hitting the correct env.py.

Any ideas on how to get past this error and create my first revision?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that after I sorted through differences between the two database structures, the core problem was the same as the one I linked to, I just needed to add all of the proper flags to make it work with two databases.
Running:

```
alembic -n 'alembic_second' stamp head --version-path=alembic_second/versions
```

solved my problems.